# Why is this call.receive<T>() deserializing json array items entirely to string type in Ktor?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

Consider the following deserialization in Ktor setup context:

- A simple model to deserialize JSON requests (aims to receive/store only Strings):

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class TestingDTO(val texts: List<String>)
```

- The Ktor entry point:

```kotlin
fun main() {
  embeddedServer(
    Netty,
    port = 8080,
    host = "0.0.0.0",
    module = Application::myApp
  ).start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.myApp() {
  install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json()
  }

  routing {
    post("/testing") {
      runCatching {
        val receivedTestingDTO = call.receive<TestingDTO>()
        println(receivedTestingDTO)
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
      }.onFailure {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, it.message ?: "deserialization problem!!!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Example of POST request to the bove setup:

```bash
curl -v -d '{"texts": ["foo", "bar", 1]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:8080/testing
```

*Note: notice the JSON array containing strings and number at same time.*

Now, if we run that, basically the `call.receive<TestingDTO>()` deserilizes the JSON of the request  to the `TestingDTO` type "perfectly", even we puting a number inside that JSON array, causing the transformation of all items from that to `String` (in order to fit them in the target `texts` list?).

However if we use as deserialization method other kotlin API, the class `kotlinx.serialization.json.Json`, the example request fails as expected. For example, the `runCatching` block:

```kotlin
      runCatching {
        // now consuming request to read raw json as "text"
        // and using kotlinx class to deserialize that text fails
        // if in request exists a diferent type that doesn't fits the target
        // TestingDTO List
        val receivedTestingDTO = Json.decodeFromString<TestingDTO>(call.receiveText())
        receivedTestingDTO.texts.forEach {
          println("the value [$it] is instance of ${it::class}")
        }
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created)
      }.onFailure {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, it.message ?: "deserialization problem!!!")
      }
    }
```

So, what exactly is happening here? Why those two different behaviours? Am I missing something about the `call.receive<>()` function specification?

If not, the "working" approach is worth of using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is the result of the [isLenient](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-builder/#1998671870%2FProperties%2F-702380584) json configuration builder.

In Ktor the default Json configuration used for all request uppon installing `ContentNegotiation` is:

```kotlin
public val DefaultJson: Json = Json {
    encodeDefaults = true
    isLenient = true
    allowSpecialFloatingPointValues = true
    allowStructuredMapKeys = true
    prettyPrint = false
    useArrayPolymorphism = false
}
```

In your example you use `Json.decodeFromString` without configuration. By default, `isLenient` is false.

You should do something like this

```kotlin
val codec = Json { 
    isLenient = true
}
val receivedTestingDTO = codec.decodeFromString<TestingDTO>(call.receiveText())
```

to have the same behavior as Ktor.

Note:

[You can force one json configuration](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html#register_json) by providing your own builder in the json function.

```kotlin
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(Json {
        prettyPrint = true
        isLenient = true
    })
}
```

Comment: Amazing, you are very right! Very small detail but important, at the end. Also, the desired behaviour suggested in the question was to the Ktor API works exacly in a "NOT lenient" mode, making me turn my configuration value as `isLenient = false`. Thanks for the reply!